# How to get Intent from PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

Can I get the `Intent` from a `PendingIntent`?

Here is the scenario:

1. I create an `Intent` (let's call it `myIntent`)
2. I put some Extra information with a String (call it `myInfo`)
3. I create a `PendingIntent` (`myPendingIntent`) using `myIntent`
4. I set an alarm using the `AlarmManager` and `myPendingIntent`
5. At a later stage I get hold of the PendingIntent using `PendingIntent.getBroadcast`
6. At that point I want to read `myInfo` from `myIntent` which is in `myPendingIntent`

Is this possible? By looking around Google, I am coming close to the conclusion that this is not possible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Nope. `PendingIntent` is a write-only interface. You can replace the `Intent`, but you cannot read it.

Comment: It seems you can get the Intent (retrieve the Extras originally stored with it) if it is currently held by AlarmManager if you call `PendingIntent.getService` (or maybe `.getBroadcast`) with the same `requestCode` as the original and *no* flags, and then immediately immediately `send()` the intent to oneself.  Is there any reason one should not use this method (is it reliable across all Android versions)?

Comment: @Michael: I haven't used it and wouldn't use it, and so I cannot comment upon its reliability. Frankly, I was dismayed to find out that it is possible.

Comment: @Michael: I don't like security flaws. I thought that the write-only interface of `PendingIntent` was in part to keep the details of the underlying `Intent` out of the hands of third parties. This is going to be exploited, but the Android security team has indicated that it is working as intended.

Comment: Ah I see. The docs do seem to warn that giving out a PendingIntent pretty much gives the receiver permission to be you, so access the Intent itself seems like the least of one's worries.

Comment: @Michael: You haven't seem what some developers put inside the extras.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible since 4.2.2 using reflection. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241657/get-details-about-intent-of-a-pendingintent/27799761#27799761), there's complete solution to obtain `Intent` from `PendingIntent`.

Comment: This solution will fail if you try and get a Parceable bundle from the intent.

Comment: On newer versions of Android, it is no longer possible to get the Intent using reflection. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/42401911/324625