# Get Intent from PendingIntent causes SecurityException

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

We have some old code that worked for a long time:

```
public static Intent getIntent(PendingIntent pendingIntent) {
    Intent intent = null;
    try {
        Method getIntent = PendingIntent.class.getDeclaredMethod("getIntent");
        intent = (Intent) getIntent.invoke(pendingIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log line
    }
    return intent;
}
```

We are now getting a security exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.company.util.IntentUtils.getIntent(IntentUtils.java:160)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getIntentForIntentSender() from pid=28128, uid=10127 requires android.permission.GET_INTENT_SENDER_INTENT
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getIntentForIntentSender(ActivityManagerNative.java:5924)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getIntent(PendingIntent.java:987)
    ... 17 more
```

Looks like it might be related to AOSP change:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/e5ad41b%5E!/

Any help getting the intend would be appreciated.

Comment: "We are now getting a security exception" -- great! I had complained about this security issue previously, and I am glad to see that this has been tightened up.

Comment: It's not like we are trying to do anything malicious we just want to persist a cached PendingIntent through a device reset or application restart.

Comment: You can't persist a cached `PendingIntent` that wasn't your own to begin with, as you cannot create the security context of the other app (unless there's some *other* security bug here...). For your own apps, rather than hacking into `PendingIntent`, keep track of which ones are outstanding by other means, since you are the one creating those `PendingIntents`.

Comment: @CubePirate - Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Libin Sorry no, we ended up changing the requirements and the implementation

Comment: better security is all fine and good, but the kind of functionality limiting the user can't override is not fun.

Answer (score 8):

There's no workaround: as per the error message and commit, that hidden method that was never part of the public API now requires a `signature` permission that only apps that are signed with the system signature can hold.

Comment: Well, isn't that sweet? And here, I had plans to conquer the world.

Comment: Sometimes you need to know what a pending intent is gonna do.

Comment: probably works on samsung if you get the permissions from seap.